# PHP, Line break when writting to a file

Tags: php, file-io, webforms, file-writing

I am trying to keep a running total of all the responses to a form I have written, but I am having trouble making it so that each response takes a new line. I have my code down below. I just want it so that it is easier to read because right now what happens is that all the responses are jammed together would like to have each one on a new line. I tried a few things and have them commented in the code and what the result was. Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sometext']))
    {
    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $thetext=$_POST['sometext'] ;//added + "\n" here but all response turned to 0 
    writemyfile($myFile,$thetext,"a");
    } else
    {
    $thetext="Enter text here";
    }

function readmyfile($thefile)
    {  
        $file = fopen($thefile, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
        //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
        while(!feof($file))
        {
            echo fgets($file). "<br />";
        }
        fclose($file);
    }

function writemyfile($thefilename,$data,$mode) 
    {
        $myfile=fopen($thefilename,$mode);
        fwrite($myfile, $data); // added + "\n" here and responses turned 0
        fclose($myfile);
    }  
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Zain's Test Site</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $php_self ?>">
            <input type="text" name="sometext" value="<?php echo $thetext ?>" >
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Click this button">
        </form>
        <?php readmyfile("testFile.txt"); ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: PHP has a constant, `PHP_EOL` which contains your host platform's end-of-line character(s). It's safer to use this than `\n`, unless you're specifically reading/writing a file for another platform.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that, I'll do some research on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try appending the newline character (\n) to the $thetext variable like this:

```
$thetext=$_POST['sometext'] . "\n";
```

Remember to use '.' as the concatenation operator, and use double-quotes around the newline character.

Comment: Thanks. Idk why I didn't realize the operator. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: This is no waste at all. That's why were here. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$thetext."\n"
```

in php you concatenate strings using ".", you use "+" in javascript.

Comment: Thanks. Idk why I didn't realize the operator. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use newline "\n" instead of the br's which is for html

Answer (score 1):

`$text = $text."\n"` ?

Err here's some more text to fill out the answer

Comment: Thanks. Idk why I didn't realize the operator. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fwrite($myfile, $data); // added + "\n" here and responses turned 0
```

the concat string operator is (.) not (+)

you can also simplify your script thusly

```
 echo nl2br(get_file_contents($file));
```

Comment: Thanks. Idk why I didn't realize the operator. Sorry for wasting your time.